# Many-to-many Authentication Pattern

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, openid, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to come up with an authentication scheme for a rather unusual scenario.

I've got multiple Azure Active Directories (potentially a few dozens), and multiple Web API services.
A customer can sign up/log in to either of the ADs and then be able to authenticate requests with either of the services.

The straightforward solution would require me to configure ALL of my services with information about ALL of the ADs.
This many-to-many relationship is what I'm trying to avoid.

I thought about the solution of building a centralised token-exchange server that will issue a normalized token, but I'm not sure how secure this method is and I'd rather use an "out of the box" solution instead of implementing my own.

How would you go about solving this?

Comment: It sounds like a multi tenant application ? Did you have a look at building multi tenant application with Azure AD ?

Comment: I looked into it. The problem is that the user shouldn't be able to choose which AD to sign in with. It should be decided by the the service that redirects the user to sign in.

Comment: Users do not choose. You enter your email and based on your email, it redirects you to the login page of your organization.

Comment: I failed to mention that the users should be able to use the same email address in more than one AD, potentially with different passwords

Answer (score 0):

The [multi-tenancy support of Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store/) is designed to solve your scenario.

First you publish the service as a multi-tenant application in Azure AD. Then the tenant directory administrator subscribes to the application by going through the consent flow.

Your service needs to set the [`ValidateIssuer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.validateissuer(v=vs.114).aspx) property of the [`TokenValidationParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters(v=vs.114).aspx) to false to disable checking the issuer of the token.

Now, users can sign in with *any directory* provided they consented the application. To limit this to only the directories you want, you can add a `IssuerValidator` delegate to the `TokenValidationParameters`.

```
IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, params) =>
{
    if (_db.FindIssuer(issuer) != null)
        return issuer;
    else
        throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Not a valid issuer");
},
```

Comment: In principle you're right, but it's not exactly my scenario.
There are some additional requirements that may collide with each other.
1. I want users to be able to use the same email address in more than one tenant (may not be a problem, but -)
2. I don't want them to be able to choose which AD to sign in with, I want to redirect them to the one I choose for them.
3. I don't want to display a consent page when they sign up. I want to create the feeling that the users are signing up directly with the provider.

Comment: Not really sure why you care with what directory the users sign in. The issued tokens will be the same except for the `tenantid` claim. Users don't chose the directory they sign in with, they just enter their credentials and Azure AD will select the correct directory based on their domain. The consent page won't be displayed for every user if the tenant admin has done a global consent.

Comment: So you want to create a custom login page and then call the Azure AD Graph API to get the authentication token ? May be you should edit your question to explain a little bit more about your need and why the default multi-tenancy does not fit you requirement. But what you describe is a multi tenant application